# Issues with meta viewport tag and css media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Okay,

I know there are a lot of questions out there on CSS media queries and meta viewport tags for responsive websites. I've read through a ton of them, but I'm not having any luck.

I have a website, a portfolio website, that I had responsive. One day, the responsive stuff just stopped working. I started looking into it and just have had no luck. I've made sure to use the meta viewport tag, but that's just not doing anything. Here's my `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and one section of the responsive CSS file:

```
@media screen and(max-width: 800px){
    /*body:before{ color: #fff; content: 'Max-Width: 800px'; }*/

    .social-media a,
    .social-media iframe{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .level2{
        height: 140px;
    }

}
```

I've also tried with and without this bit of code:

```
@-o-viewport,
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}
```

The frustrating thing is that at work I just finished a responsive site and had no issues. I figure maybe another set of eyes may be able to catch something that I haven't been able to.

You can see the website at pjlamb12.github.io, and it will look fine in a desktop but not like I want it to on any mobile devices.

Thanks!

P.S.

I don't know if this matters, but the site is on GitHub pages, and I'm using Jekyll to run the site.

EDIT

The rest of the code can also be seen in GitHub here https://github.com/pjlamb12/pjlamb12.github.com

Comment: In the CSS file, those styles you mention are commented out.

Comment: I know that one is, but styles later on in the document don't work either.

Comment: But then what are the things that should differ between large browsers and mobile ones? Can you give an actual example, I mean, one that isn't commented out?

Comment: Okay, there's a real example, the second level of the main navigation is supposed to have a height change when the browser window gets smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured out the problem. Really stupid, small problem. It was in my media queries line; here's what I had:

```
@media screen and(max-width: 800px){
    /* styles */
}
```

But what you have to have is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
    /* styles */
}
```

Did you notice the difference? It took me a few minutes, but there HAS to be a space between the `and` and the `(` on that first line.

Hopefully if anyone else has this issue, they'll see this and try it first thing.

Thanks!